# Scrapy. Crawl whole site and return a single value: total number of links

Tags: python, scrapy

It's easy to crawl the whole website

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        extractor =LinkExtractor(allow_domains='quotes.toscrape.com')
        links = extractor.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link.url, self.parse)
        yield {'url': response.url}
```

But how can I return a single value? Total number of links.

Answer (score 0):

For stats about the crawl, use [Scrapy Stats](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html).

```
self.stats.inc_value('link_count')
```

The stats will be available as `spider.stats`.

The stats can be recovered from a ScrapyCloud project using the [metadata() API](https://python-scrapinghub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/overview.html#metadata):

```
from scrapinghub import ScrapinghubClient

client  = ScrapinghubClient()

pro = client.get_project(<PROJECT_ID>)
job = pro.jobs.get(<JOB_ID>)

stats = job.metadata.get('scrapystats')
```

.

```
>>> job.metadata.get('scrapystats')
...
'downloader/response_count': 104,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 104,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': 1447160494937,
'item_scraped_count': 50,
'log_count/DEBUG': 157,
'log_count/INFO': 1365,
'log_count/WARNING': 3,
'memusage/max': 182988800,
'memusage/startup': 62439424,
...
```

Comment: Thank you. And how can I return it  at the end of the crawl?